# Question about Eclipse installation error on a new laptop

Tags: spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

An internal error occurred during: "Classpath Dependency Validator". Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants. I recently bought a new laptop and downloaded Eclipse 2021 March version, but when I try to use Spring, it doesn't work and shows me the error message above. Can anyone help me? Has anyone experienced the same error?
i can't see project facets than empty;

remove and reinstall install software and fix eclipse ini file

Comment: Why a 2 year / 8 release old version? Exactly what download?